# For a rigid body in equilibrium (both translational & rotational), is the net torque about any axis of rotation zero?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

Is the net torque about any point zero for a body in equilibrium? Or the net torque only about the centre of mass zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok let us see. The torque for the force $\vec F$ is given by:
$$\vec r \times \vec F$$
Thus the total torque on a body with respect to the position  $\vec p$ is given by:
$$\vec \tau(\vec p)=\sum_i (\vec r_i -\vec p)\times \vec F_i$$
where all positions vectors are measured from the origin. Let us suppose that this is zero for one value of $\vec p$ then relative to the point $\vec p+\vec p'$ we have that:
$$\vec \tau(\vec p+\vec p')=\sum_i (\vec r_i -\vec p-\vec  p')\times \vec F_i$$
$$=\tau(\vec p)- \vec p' \times \sum_i \vec F_i$$
$$=- \vec p' \times \sum_i \vec F_i$$
But if we are in equilibrium 
$$\sum_i \vec F_i=0$$
so:
$$\tau(\vec p+\vec p')=0$$
i.e. in equilibrium if $\tau(\vec p)$ for any $\vec p$ (e.g. the cofm) then it is zero for all $\vec p$.

Answer (score 2):

[image: CM Center of mass]

**For a rigid body in equilibrium , is the net torque about any axis of rotation zero**?
\begin{align*}
  &\text{Static:}\\\\
  &\text{Coordinate system center of mass $CM$}\\\\
  &\vec{f}_1+\vec{f_2}=0\,,\text{Forces}\\
  &\vec{f}_1\times\vec{r_1}+\vec{f}_2\times\vec{r_2}=0\,,\text{Torques}\\\\
  &\text{Coordinate system  $P$ : Torques }\\\\
  &\vec{f}_1\times\vec{r'_1}+\vec{f}_2\times\vec{r'_2}=
  \vec{f}_1\times\left(\vec{r_1}+\vec{r_3}\right)+
  \vec{f}_2\times\left(\vec{r_2}+\vec{r_3}\right)
  =\underbrace{\vec{f}_1\times \vec{r}_1+\vec{f}_2\times\vec{r}_2}_{=0}+
  \underbrace{\left(\vec{f}_1+\vec{f}_2\right)}_{=0}\times \vec{r}_3=0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\text{General case}\\\\
  &\text{Coordinate system $CM$}\\\\
 &\sum_{i}^{k} \vec{f}_i=0\\
  &\sum_{i}^{k} \vec{f}_i\times \vec{r}_i=0\\
   &\text{Coordinate system  $P$ }\\\\
   &\sum_{i}^{k} \vec{f}_i\times \vec{r'}_i=
   \sum_{i}^{k} \vec{f}_i\times \left(\vec{r}_i+\vec{r}_{CP}\right)=
   \sum_{i}^{k} \vec{f}_i\times \vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_{CP}\sum_{i}^{k}\vec{f}_i=0
\end{align*}